# Revert variables inside a Loop in Node JS

Tags: node.js

I am trying one logic in Node JS code which looks something like below:-

```
var startPersons1 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(persons1));
var startPersons2 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(persons2));
var startPersons3 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(persons3));
var startPersons4 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(persons4));

.....
// Operations on persons1, persons2, persons3, persons4 which are changed in methods called here
....

// Now persons1, persons2, persons3, persons4 are modified

// Now, if I wanted persons1, persons2, persons3, persons4 to come to their original state above, ie.
// startPersons1, startPersons2, startPersons3, startPersons4, I am doing something like this

persons1 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(startPersons1));
persons2 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(startPersons2));
persons3 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(startPersons3));
persons4 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(startPersons4));
```

You can assume this is inside some for loop.
So, is there a better way to do this revert everytime. The number of variables can increase by lot.

Comment: Put them in an array and use `.map`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if persons1, persons2 etc are inside an array, you could use map function

```
var persons = [/*array of persons*/]
var newpersons = persons.map(function(person) {
    /*change here your person object and return it.*/
    return person
})
/*here persons is the originalone, newpersone is the new version*/
```